# Excluir registro SQL com dependencia

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, delete

Boa tarde.

Gostaria de saber como excluir registros de uma tabela contendo chave estrangeira.

Eu não gostaria de excluir os registros filhos (para manter o historico).

Sempre recebo uma mensagem alertando que existem dependencias ao tentar atualizar um registro pai.

Comment: Era exatamente isso! Infelizmente eu não consegui implementar o set null através do workbench... O que fiz para contornar o problema foi a criação de uma nova coluna na tabela Pai para identificar os registros que foram excluidos. Deste modo a chave estrangeira foi mantida. Eu até pensei em algo como uma tabela clone, mas não saberia implementar sem estudar um pouquinho rs.  Obrigado pela Ajuda!!!

Answer (score 2):

Ao criar a chave estrangeira é possível definir o seu comportamento quando houver um `DELETE`:

`NO ACTION`: Não é permitido apagar o registo pai. É gerada uma mensagem de erro.

`CASCADE`: Toda a linha do registo filho é apagada.

`SET NULL`: os registos filhos são mantidos, mas o valor na coluna que tem a chave estrangeira é colocado a `NULL`.

`SET DEFAULT`: coloca um valor por defeito definido.

Caso nenhuma se enquadre, a solução pode passar por remover a chave estrangeira ou manter uma tabela clone, para histórico, sem chave estrangeira.

Comment: defeito ? defeito